# Magento2: Import Export to update multiple product attribute settings?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, import, export

Can I use Magento2 's Import or Export features under Settings in the Admin to make this change: 
"Storefront Properties - Allow HTML tags on Storefront, change to Yes" 
for multiple product attributes, instead of updating this manually for the list of product attributes?